# Question involving Family of operators and diagonalization.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and let  $\mathcal{F}$ a family of diagonalizable operators such that, for all $T,G \in \mathcal{F}$ we have $T\circ G = G \circ T$. Show that there is a basis $B$ of $V$ where $[T]_{B}$ is diagonal for all $T \in \mathcal{F}$.

Things that I figure out about this exercise:

If $T \circ G  = G \circ T$, then $E_\lambda=\{v \in V: Tv= \lambda v\}$ is $G-$invariant.

Indeed, let $v \in E_\lambda$ then $T(G(v)) = G(T(v)) = G(\lambda v) = \lambda G(v)$. So we have $G(v) \in E_\lambda$.

When $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of multiples of identity operator then the result is obvious.

But in the general, how to solve that?

My professor sad to use induction em $\dim V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor's hint is good.

Assume first that $\dim V=1$. Then, the statement is obvious.

Now assume that we've proven the statement for $\dim V=n$. Then, for $\dim V=n+1,$ as you've noted, the statement is trivial if every $T\in \mathcal{F}$ is a multiple of the identity. Accordingly, we can assume $T\in\mathcal{F}$ with at least two distinct Eigenvectors. Hence, $V=\oplus_{\lambda\in \sigma(T)} E_{\lambda}$ and each $E_{\lambda}$ has dimension at most $n$.

Since each $E_{\lambda}$ is $G$-invariant for every $G\in \mathcal{F}$, we can apply the induction hypothesis to $E_{\lambda}$ and get that each $E_{\lambda}$ admits a basis $\{v^{\lambda}_j\}_{1\leq j\leq \dim (E_{\lambda})}$ such that $v^{\lambda}_j$ is an Eigenvector of every $G\in \mathcal{F}$. Then, of course, $\{v^{\lambda}_j\}_{\lambda\in \sigma(T),1\leq j\leq \dim(E_\lambda)}$ is a basis of $V$ and we're done.

Comment: could you be more clear? please, I still didn't get it

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could ask a more specific question. Which part(s) are causing you confusion at the moment?

Comment: Why $\{v_j^{\lambda\} is a basis of V$?

Comment: $V=\oplus_{\lambda\in \sigma(T)} E_{\lambda}$, so I can give you a basis of $V$ by giving you a basis of each $E_{\lambda}$.